# How to test custom django-admin commands

Tags: django, testing, django-admin, custom-action

I created [custom django-admin commands](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

But, I don't know how to test it in [standard django tests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you're using some coverage tool it would be good to call it from the code with:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import TestCase

class CommandsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_mycommand(self):
        " Test my custom command."

        args = []
        opts = {}
        call_command('mycommand', *args, **opts)

        # Some Asserts.
```

[From the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#management-commands)

> Management commands can be tested with the call_command() function. The output can be redirected into a StringIO instance

Comment: Note the How to covers testing https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/#testing

Comment: The above link is broken, access the latest version of mentioned doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#testing).

Comment: My command creates entries in the database, do you know how to use the testdb ?

Comment: @SWater Hi, as far as I understand, the `TestCase` from `django.test` uses the test database, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

Answer (score 23):

You should make your actual command script the minimum possible, so that it just calls a function elsewhere. The function can then be tested via unit tests or doctests as normal.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this. If I could do that, I probably would not make it a Django command. I would just run it as a python program. The reason I make Django commands is to get all the Django infrastructure.

Comment: Well, sometimes you can't just run it as a python program because of the import issues.

Answer (score 20):

you can see in github.com example
[see here](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/blob/921b432bbb8bc7c8d3863061492f8606c0fbbc33/AppServer/lib/django-1.2/tests/modeltests/user_commands/tests.py)

```
from StringIO import StringIO

from django.test import TestCase
from django.core import management

class CommandTests(TestCase):

    def test_command_style(self):
        out = StringIO()
        management.call_command('dance', style='Jive', stdout=out)
        self.assertEquals(out.getvalue(), "I don't feel like dancing Jive.")
```

Comment: mybe you need  
    out.getvalue().strip()

Answer (score 7):

To add to what has already been posted here. If your django-admin command passes a file as parameter, you could do something like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management import call_command
from io import StringIO
import os


class CommandTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_command_import(self):
        out = StringIO()
        call_command(
            'my_command', os.path.join('path/to/file', 'my_file.txt'),
            stdout=out
        )
        self.assertIn(
        'Expected Value',
            out.getvalue()
        )
```

This works when your django-command is used in a manner like this:

```
$ python manage.py my_command my_file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple alternative to [parsing stdout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-management-commands) is to make your management command exit with an error code if it doesn't run successfully, for example using sys.exit(1).

You can catch this in a test with:

```
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
        call_command('mycommand')
```

Answer (score -3):

I agree with Daniel that the actual command script should do the minimum possible but you can also test it directly in a Django unit test using `os.popen4`.

From within your unit test you can have a command like

```
fin, fout = os.popen4('python manage.py yourcommand')
result = fout.read()
```

You can then analyze the contents of result to test whether your Django command was successful.

Comment: don't use subprocesses for this kind of testing, and certainly don't use os.popen4, if you really wanted to do that you'd use the subprocess package.